# Parsing image.get() object as number

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am attempting to include images only if they contain a certain level of pixel coverage within an area of interest. I have a value for this percentage cover which has been set as a property in the image. When I use image.get it returns as the correct number, but as an object which I cannot seem to compare to the cutoff number.

```
    var thisCoverage = (image.get('percCover'))
    
    if (thisCoverage != COVERAGEPERCENT) {
      print('not good enough')
      print(typeof thisCoverage) // returns object
      print(typeof COVERAGEPERCENT) // returns number
    }
```

Here `thisCoverage` is being compared to a constant value (100). If an image is put through that has complete coverage (`percCover` of 100) it still returns 'not good enough'. I have tried using `ee.Number` which does not appear to make a difference.

Any suggestions? Can I compare an object to a number? How can I parse this object as a number?

*Edit: Fixed! For anyone interested, I used `.getInfo` to get the number within the object

Comment: Instead of answering the question in the Question, please post an Answer. As is, the question is subject to being closed as *unreproducible*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to do it is with a filterMetadata().

```
var filteredImageCollection = yourImageCollection.filterMetadata('percCover', 'equals', COVERAGEPERCENT);
```